# How to make an overflow horizontal cards with arrows? (using Bootstrap 4.5)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I a snippet like this (using bootstrap) and it can make an overflow card that can be scrolled horizontally.

```html
<div class="container">
    {{-- If you look to others for fulfillment, you will never truly be fulfilled. --}}
    <h4 class="mb-4">Header Title</h4>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-scroll">
        <div class="overflow-auto row flex-row flex-nowrap mt-4 pb-4 pt-2">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img src="https://imgix.kitabisa.com/8bd765d4-2fa3-4ba5-a983-7d1ddee51705.jpg?ar=16:9&w=280&auto=format,compress"
                        class="img-fluid rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>Rp 20.000.000</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right">
                                    <p>4 hari lagi</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img src="https://imgix.kitabisa.com/8bd765d4-2fa3-4ba5-a983-7d1ddee51705.jpg?ar=16:9&w=280&auto=format,compress"
                        class="img-fluid rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>Rp 20.000.000</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right">
                                    <p>4 hari lagi</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img src="https://imgix.kitabisa.com/8bd765d4-2fa3-4ba5-a983-7d1ddee51705.jpg?ar=16:9&w=280&auto=format,compress"
                        class="img-fluid rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>Rp 20.000.000</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right">
                                    <p>4 hari lagi</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img src="https://imgix.kitabisa.com/8bd765d4-2fa3-4ba5-a983-7d1ddee51705.jpg?ar=16:9&w=280&auto=format,compress"
                        class="img-fluid rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>Rp 20.000.000</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right">
                                    <p>4 hari lagi</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live demo can be seen here : https://codepen.io/yehezkiel-g/pen/vYXbmxQ

Now the problem is that I want to make left and right arrow for the navigation like this picture below.
[image]

Any suggestion for this? I'm using Laravel Livewire by the way. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.
Make carousel, prev/next buttons:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary-outline prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary-outline next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

https://www.codeply.com/go/WEbiqQvGhy

Comment: https://codepen.io/yehezkiel-g/pen/zYKezxL
Like that??? The arrow exist but it cannot navigate the contents. Correct me if I wrong in this snippet